# OnExit Event For a Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, exit

I'm developing a simple application to manage the operational part of a business using Swing, but I need that when the application exits, it performs this:

```
updateZonas();
db.close();
```

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        updateZonas();
        db.close();
    }
});
```

This works for any Java application(Swing/AWT/Console)

Comment: @vemv why is it **too** low level?  Surely if you need to intercept the exit event under any condition you need a low level hook?

Answer (score 29):

Are you using a JFrame? if so you can try this:

```
    myframe.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEvt) {
            updateZonas();
            db.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also put a try/catch/finally around the updateZonas and dbclose calls in case something is wrong. You can let the user know something went wrong and decide whether or not the app should still exit.

Comment: Is the `System.exit(0);` necessary?

Comment: No it should not be necessary.

Comment: Side note: This does not work on OSGi services if another service is closing it.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `WindowListener` to your JFrame. Its `windowClosing` method would call whatever code you need, then `System.exit(0)` (or some other return code).