# On Close button action Java

Tags: java

Sorry if there is a question like this already but I couldn't find it.
I found things like how to create a button listener and people create a button and perform action on it. I want when the close button ( x button ) is pressed a warning window to pop-up and say that the project is not saved.  I couldn't find how to access the close button. How to use a button listener with the close button?  Hope made myself clear. 
Thanks

Comment: Look through the answers to [OnExit Event For a Swing Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467070/onexit-event-for-a-swing-application).

Comment: I think this link is what your are looking for :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093448/do-something-when-the-close-button-is-clicked-on-a-jframe

Comment: thanks, it seems I couldn't google it right ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `WindowAdapter`  to your `JFrame`.

```
myFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
  @Override
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
     // do something
  }
});
```

Now, every time someone presses the close button, the `windowClosing()` method will be called. Check if the user has saved the work. If not, either auto-save it like or promprt user to save it.

Answer (score 1):

overload the close/exit action

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

[Create custom operation for setDefaultCloseOperation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084039/create-custom-operation-for-setdefaultcloseoperation)

define a method separately and add listener for close action.